# in spring boot 2.1 many test slices are not allowed anymore due to multiple @BootstrapWith

Tags: spring-boot-test

I tried to upgrade a yummy sandwich made of two test slices (@JsonTest and @JdbcTest in my case, crunchy test code in between) adding spring boot 2.1 flavour to it. But it seems it was not much of a success. I cannot annotate my tests with many @...Test since they are now each bringing their own XxxTestContextBootstrapper. It used to work when they all used same SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@JdbcTest
@JsonTest
public class Test {
  @Test
  public void test() { System.out.printn("Hello, World !"); }
}
```

The error I get from BootstrapUtils is illegalStateException :
Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class

I understand I might be doing something wrong here but is there an easy way I could load both Json and Jdbc contexts ?

Comment: What is the exception that do you have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Test slice annotations aren't really designed to be composed like that. Your code worked in Spring Boot 2.0 only by luck I'm afraid.

You really need to pick just one `@...Test` annotation and then combine it with one or more `@AutoConfigure...` annotations. For the example above, I would write:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@JdbcTest
@AutoConfigureJson
@AutoConfigureJsonTesters
public class Test {

  @Test
  public void test() { 
    System.out.println("Hello, World !"); 
  }

}
```